# Select syntax not displaying correctly (Not sure if duplicate)

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I am currently working on a project in grad school. I am constructing a database that is writeable as well as searchable. I have completed the writeable aspect, however I am having issues with the search function. THe issue is I am unable to search and display an individual row in the database, only the entire database, which lets be honest, not very functional if a database has 20k items and you only need 20.

I am copying the code in its entirety below.

```
        <?php
        ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
        error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);

        // --------------------------------------------------------
        /* THIS DEMO FILE ACCEPTS DATA FROM A WEB FORM
        AND SAVES THE DATA TO A FLAT FILE AND THEN TO A DATABASE.
        AS A CHECK WE READ THE DATA BACK FROM THE TABLE AND FROM
        THE FILE.
        Created by: PATRICK DUFF, based on example written by G. Benoit, on 2/28/15 
        Modified on: 3/1/15, 3/5/15/ 3/13/15
        Contact: xxxxxxx
        */
        // --------------------------------------------------------
        /* GETTING READY FOR THE DATA */
        /* the file to hold the data */
        $filename = "testData.txt";
        $status = "";
        /* name of the database, table, username, password, table */
        $hostname = "xxxxxxx"; // change this vars for your own db
        $username = "xxxxx"; // whatever your student email user name is
        $password = "xxxxx"; // your usual password
        $dbname = "xxxxxx"; // this database name is assigned for you by the Lab Staff Lab Staff
        $table = "xxxxxx"; // once you’re using your DB, you can create your own tables

        //getting data from webfrom

        $isbn = $_POST["isbn"];
        $lname = $_POST["lname"];
        $fname = $_POST["fname"];
        $title = $_POST["title"];
        $publisher = $_POST["publisher"];
        $genre = $_POST["genre"];
        $con = mysqli_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");
    $isbn = $_POST["isbn"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$publisher = $_POST["publisher"];
$genre = $_POST["genre"];
$con = mysqli_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password", "$dbname");

//retrieving data from flat form & database.

echo "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head> <title> Record Search </title></head>";
echo "<body> Here is the data: The file contents of 'testData.txt so far is/are: ";
echo file_get_contents($filename);
echo "<hr /> End of reading file. Attempting to read database <hr />";
//creating searchability
$sql= "SELECT * FROM myLibrary WHERE isbn LIKE '%" .$isbn." %' OR fname LIKE '%" .$fname." %' OR lname LIKE'%" .$lname." %' OR title LIKE '%" .$title." %' OR publisher LIKE '%" .$publisher." %' OR genre LIKE'%" .$genre."%'  ORDER BY lname"  or
    die(mysql_error());
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

//displays result in table
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table id='myLibrary'><tr><th><u>ISBN</u></th><th> <u>First Name</u></th><th><u> Last Name </u></th><th><u> Title</u> </th><th><u>Publisher</u></th> <th><u>Genre</u></th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["isbn"]."</td><td>". $row["fname"]."</td><td>" . $row["lname"]. "</td><td>" .$row["title"]. "</td><td>" .$row["publisher"]. "</td><td>".$row["genre"]. "</td></tr>";
    }   
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

echo "End of Results";
```

For some reason when I comment out the table, nothing from the table gets displayed.

I hope this was clear enough, it's my first time posting here.

Comment: `OR lname LIKE'%` should be `OR lname LIKE '%`

Comment: `$sql= "SELECT …"  or die(mysql_error());` – that is total nonsense. Apart from that you are using `mysqli` functions everywhere else – assigning a string value to a variable can not in itself cause a database error.

Comment: What do you mean, "when I edit out the table" ?  Also, I suggest you investigate FULLTEXT indexing and searching. `WHERE a LIKE '%match%'` is notorious for being the very slowest way to search a database.  Also, don't mix `mysqii_` calls and `mysql_` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to limit the query to avoid returning all the results.

```
$limit = 10;
$sql= "SELECT * FROM myLibrary WHERE isbn LIKE '%" .$isbn." %' OR fname LIKE '%" .$fname." %' OR lname LIKE'%" .$lname." %' OR title LIKE '%" .$title." %' OR publisher LIKE '%" .$publisher." %' OR genre LIKE'%" .$genre."%'  ORDER BY lname LIMIT " .$limit . ""
```